# g++ failed to print meaningful error message in linking

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, ld, error-messaging

In my environment, in failed linking case of g++, only `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status` reported:

```bash
bsl@ubuntu:~/compiletest$ g++ -v main.o
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --enable-bootstrap --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccp5JiC8.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../.. main.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
bsl@ubuntu:~/compiletest$
```

Linking by ld directly, the meaningful error message printed:

```bash
bsl@ubuntu:~/compiletest$ /usr/bin/ld --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../.. main.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Foo::foo_pub(int)'
bsl@ubuntu:~/compiletest$
```

OS:

```bash
bsl@ubuntu:~/compiletest$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.3.0-18-generic #19-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 8 20:14:06 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've read some references, and guess that channel between `collect2` and `ld` has been broken. But I can not come up with a solution currently.

[error routine](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2018-09/msg00545.html)

[collect-utils.cc](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/collect-utils.cc)

[link options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html)

How to solve it? Or, if there is a straightforward way to tell the g++ to invoke ld without collect2 directly?

Thank you very much!